# Is it possible to create ObjectId in Mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, objectid, mongo-shell

I'm updating a document with an array of embedded documents, directly in Mongo shell. I would like each of these sub-docs to have an `_id` field, but these are not created automatically as they are for top-level documents. Is there a way to simply create an new ObjectId in Mongo shell? Something along the lines of (below example is not valid):

```
"prop": [
  {
    "_id": new ObjectId(), // creates the objectId when executing the line
    "foo": "bar"
  }
]
```

The main requirement is not having to manually generate random strings for each doc to create. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible. You can generate ObjectId

```
ObjectId id = new ObjectId();

// or this
ObjectId id = ObjectId.get();
```

Then it can be used for update doc. Hope it helps.